# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' error is displayed but binding works correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

im seeing Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' error for my angular components, but binding works correctly and everything is working fine but this error is always there is this some kind of bug?

i have formsmodule imported and tried to restart.

Comment: please provide a stackblitz example